# python - adding quotes for an each word and symbol on a text file

Tags: python, regex

I want to put quotation marks between each words and symbols on a text file.

For instance;

> Türkiye ya da resmî adıyla Türkiye Cumhuriyeti, topraklarının büyük
>   bölümü Anadolu'ya, küçük bir bölümü ise Balkanlar'ın uzantısı olan
>   Trakya'ya yayılmış bir ülke.

becomes ->

> "Türkiye" "ya" "da" "resmî" "adıyla" "Türkiye" "Cumhuriyeti" ","
>   "topraklarının" "büyük" "bölümü" "Anadolu'ya" "," "küçük" "bir"
>   "bölümü" "ise" "Balkanlar'ın" "uzantısı" "olan" "Trakya'ya" "yayılmış"
>   "bir" "ülke" "."

For this reason, I have written such a code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re, codecs, io

with io.open ("turkish.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as myfile:
    text=myfile.read()

replacer = re.compile("([\w'-]+|[.,!?;()%])", re.UNICODE)

output_text = replacer.sub(r'"\1"', text).replace('""','" "')

text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")
text_file.write(output_text.encode('utf8'))
text_file.close()
```

On the example above, the replacement is fine.

But for such an example,

> İmparatorluk zirvesini 15 ve 17'nin arasında, özelikle I. Süleyman
>   döneminde 10.000'lerde yaşadı.

the replacement occurs as following;

> "İmparatorluk" "zirvesini" "15" "ve" "17'" "nin" "arasında",
>   "özelikle" "I" "." "Süleyman" "döneminde" "10" "." "000'" "lerde"
>   "yaşadı" "."

As you see, `10.000` is a number, `17'nin` is together, and `I.` refers to roman numeral ranking, so I want them to be seperated as

`10.000`, `17'nin`, and `I.`.

How should I modify my regex or code to achieve that?

Thanks,

Comment: Try `replacer = re.compile("([[\d+\.?\d+]|[\w'-]]+|[.,!?;()%])", re.UNICODE)`

Comment: No, it didn't work out. It gave such an output. Geçmişi MÖ "1" "0" "." "0" "0" "0" tarihine kadar uzanan Göbekli Tepe"," ülke toprakları üzerindeki bilinen en eski dini yapının bulunduğu yerdir"."

Comment: I would suggest you to use `split()` rather than `regex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `[IVXLCDM]+\.|[\d\.]+(?:'\w+)?` to the beginning of the regex pattern matches the "10.000" and "10.000'lerde" and "I." as intended.

```
replacer = re.compile(r"\b([IVXLCDM]+\.|[\d\.]+(?:'\w+)?|[\w'-]+|[.,!?;()%])", re.UNICODE)
```

Comment: Beware: this matches 1.2.3.4.5.6. Is it really wanted?

Comment: @serge I also assumed that the dot is used as a thousands' separator based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Examples_of_use

Comment: Martin, I have updated my question. Can you take a look?

Comment: Martin, it works for 17'nin and 10.000, but it doesn't work for I. I mean, for roman numerals.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("turkish.txt", "r") as myfile:
    text=myfile.read()

output_text = text.split(" ")

with open("Output.txt", "w",) as outfile:
    for word in output_text:
        outfile.write(' "'+ word + '" ')
```

May be a better solution